# saml call back url with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml

I have to authenticate user either by saml or by database credentials depending on how user wishes to get authenticated .
I am stuck with two problems 
1)I am receiving the saml response to the call back back url. I am not sure how to integrate it with devise.
2)I am not sure how to authenticate the user either by database or by saml response dynamically based on user choice.

Any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: I don't think SAML is what you want. I think you want OAuth. Devices won't be able to take part in the SAML game very easily.

Comment: @Andrew I am receiving response in SAML. I have a call back ur to which i get the response. I should be parsing the response and populating the uid parameter in users table using devise

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a WebView to embed the logon page in your App.

1. If the user chooses Database logon you will have to challenge the user to submit their user name and password. Once the user is identified by your API, your business logic will be kicked in.
2. If the user chooses SAML login, it will be federated login and you will send the Authen Request to the Idp. The Idp page will be rendered in WebView within your app. Once the Idp will identify the user after logon process, they would redirect the page to the URL as specified in your Authen request for the attribute AssertionConsumerService. You will have to intercept the Request to extract the SAML token which you will have to eventually submit in a API service in your environment. The API service will have to do the token processing and will generate a User profile that is identical to the one generated by the database authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented SAML with Devise in my application, and found that the [omniauth-saml](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) gem is the quickest route to getting it to work. It will handle your callback flow, usage of the `ruby-saml` library, and all the other details that would be a pain to implement on your own. And if you need to handle an arbitrary number of SAML providers, [omniauth-multi-provider-saml](https://github.com/salsify/omniauth-multi-provider-saml) worked well for me.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs Robert. In my case there are only two things 1)IDP url            2)call_back url   .   There is no secret key or any other parameter to be configured . If you could provide a working example .It will be really helpful

Comment: See here: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml#devise-integration. The implementation of omniauth-saml is the same as a normal omniauth integration, with slightly different configuration for the SAML portion. Try following the guide they link to (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) and let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: Hi Robert, I followed the link to send the request to saml by adding user_omniauth_authorize_path(:saml) but when i send the request ,**SAMLRequest**  parameter is getting appended to the idp_sso_target_url . Due to which I am getting Bad Request exception from my federation server. Is there a way to avoid adding of the **SAMLRequest** parameter

Comment: I would expect the initial request to the IdP's SSO target URL to include that SAMLRequest parameter, since it's the start of the SAML assertion. It's possible the Bad Request exception is due to something else, like a certificate mismatch. Does your IdP have SAML logs you can check?

Comment: If i remove the SAMLRequest  parameter  the the federation request goes through successfully . We have agreement with federation to send one secret parameter in the request to verify it as a authentic request. Since SAMLRequest is getting appended in the URL along with the secret parameter. We are getting this bad request error

Comment: When access the idp url directly from browser, I am able to login successful to the fedearotion But  In the call back controller i recieve **request.env["omniauth.auth"]** as nil